# Should I install via alien or just convert and then use dpkg?

Tags: package-management, alien

The question is simple (maybe too simple):
what does `alien` do when with the `-i` option? Does it use `dpkg` to install the package?

`dpkg` (or `apt-get`) manages packages, tracks when, where and how they are installed, dependencies also..
So I would like to install a package via the managing system to have these advantages. Does `alien -i` do it for me?

PS googled for an answer -- not that lucky today, `man alien` doesn't say much on `-i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO you should be very careful with alien as the packaging of say .rpm and .deb are very different. Alien can sometimes convert packages, but sometimes there can be significant problems and sometimes say Fedora libs conflict with Debian / Ubuntu libs. Also your converted package can overwrite system files without warning (obviously as it is installing packages). Last, pre/post install scripting is somewhat different from .rpm and .deb and Alien can not always convert the scripts.

IMO you are much better off either installing from source code using checkinstall

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall

Although occasionally checkinstall can have similar issues.

Personally I read the README and usually just compile form source into /usr/local

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```